# SQL Remove Duplicate Rows with Condition

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
TABLE cars
id |     name    |   prodDate   |  fuelType  |  registered  |
1      'Abarth'        2012           1            true
2      'Acura'         2022           2            true
3      'Acura'         2022           2            false
4      'Alfa Romeo'    2013           2            false
5      'Aston Martin'  2005           1            true
6      'Bentley'       2007           1            false
7      'BMW'           2019           2            false
8      'BMW'           2016           2            false
9      'Chevrolet'     2021           2            true
10     'Citroen'       2018           2            false
11     'Ferrari'       2015           2            true
12     'Ferrari'       2015           2            false
13     'Ferrari'       2014           2            false
14     'GMC'           2008           2            true
```

I need to write SQL script to delete all the duplicate rows (duplicate rows are the ones with the same `name` value) in which the `registered` is `true`. I must consider `fuelType = 1` only.

For example row `id = 11` will be deleted because there are duplicate `Ferrari` rows and this is the one with `registered = true`. Row `id = 9` won't be deleted, as there are no duplicate rows with `name = Chevrolet`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Ferrari has fuel type 2.

Comment: Do EXISTS with a correlated subquery.

Comment: What is your DBMS? Please always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS in order to get answers that work for you.

Comment: And "I must consider fuelType = 1 only" is unclear. As DannySlor already mentioned, your example Ferrari is fuelType = 2. Then, what does "consider" mean? You only want to look at fueltype-2 rows, only select those and only examine those for duplicates? You want to select all rows, but only remove rows where the "good" row is fueltype-1? You want to select all rows, but only remove rows where the "bad" row is fueltype-1? Something else still? Please show the desired result in the same form as you have shown the table data.

Answer (score 0):

We use `rank()` to find all the duplicates where `registered = true` and get rid of them.

```
select id   
      ,name 
      ,proddate 
      ,fueltype 
      ,registered
from   (
       select *
              ,rank() over(partition by name order by registered) as rnk
       from   cars 
       ) cars
where  rnk = 1
```

| id | name | proddate | fueltype | registered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Abarth | 2012 | 1 | true |
| 3 | Acura | 2022 | 2 | false |
| 4 | Alfa Romeo | 2013 | 2 | false |
| 5 | Aston Martin | 2005 | 1 | true |
| 6 | Bentley | 2007 | 1 | false |
| 8 | BMW | 2016 | 2 | false |
| 7 | BMW | 2019 | 2 | false |
| 9 | Chevrolet | 2021 | 2 | true |
| 10 | Citroen | 2018 | 2 | false |
| 12 | Ferrari | 2015 | 2 | false |
| 13 | Ferrari | 2014 | 2 | false |
| 14 | GMC | 2008 | 2 | true |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3JXeTJe2)

Answer (score 0):

With the combination of CTE and Row_number(), we can delete the duplicate records from the table.
use the below-attached script to delete duplicate rows with the same name value in which the registered is true:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY c.id) as RN
   FROM cars c
   WHERE c.registered='true'
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1;
```

This will work for you. Please let me know if any additional information is needed on this. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

when I normally get into such a situation I normally use a GROUP BY with HAVING take this example, I hope it helps

```
 SELECT fstName, 
    lstName, 
    COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM Employee
      GROUP BY fstName,lstName
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1; //those that have count more than once
```

Comment: maybe you can derive an idea from it